# PowerShell to filter all Users by two Custom Attributes, if they are Hidden from GAL, and also check if O365 has Forwarding setup

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

I am trying to write a PowerShell script at the moment that will allow me to view all AD Users who have two specific Custom Attributes set. I am filtering by this. For those users I also am pulling if they are Hidden from the GAL. I also need to somehow be able to check if they have forwarding setup on their O365 account. Is this all possible with one script. Here is currently what I have but am drawing a blank moving forward as this is not working. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the code:

`$UserList = Get-ADUser -Filter {ExtensionAttribute1 -Like "*" -AND ExtensionAttribute2 -Like "*"} -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, ExtensionAttribute1,ExtensionAttribute2,msExchHideFromAddressLists | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, ExtensionAttribute1, ExtensionAttribute2, msExchHideFromAddressLists; Get-Mailbox -Identity $UserList | select ForwardingSmtpAddress, DeliverToMailboxAndForward`

Comment: When you ask is it possible in one script, the answer is yes because you technically have one script already posted. If you mean can you do it in one command, then that is possible as well, but would likely be less efficient because you would need to perform a `Get-Mailbox` for each user.

Comment: Okay, that is interesting. Would it possible to do a ```foreach``` for ```Get-Mailbox``` and use the ```-Identity``` as the variable I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
$Params = @{
        Filter = "ExtensionAttribute1 -Like '*' -AND ExtensionAttribute2 -Like '*'"
        Properties = 'DisplayName','EmailAddress','ExtensionAttribute1','ExtensionAttribute2','msExchHideFromAddressLists'
}

$UserList = Get-ADUser @Params
foreach ($User in $UserList) {
    $Mailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity $User.EmailAddress
    $User | Select-Object DisplayName,EmailAddress,ExtensionAttribute1,ExtensionAttribute2,msExchHideFromAddressLists,
            @{n='ForwardingSmtpAddress';e={$Mailbox.ForwardingSmtpAddress}},
            @{n='DeliverToMailboxAndForward';e={$Mailbox.DeliverToMailboxAndForward}}
}
```

The code stores the AD user data as a collection in `$UserList`. That collection is iterated using a `foreach` loop to perform `Get-Mailbox` on each user. The `Select-Object` statement combines the user and mailbox object data using calculated properties. This code will output to the console. If you want it stored in a variable, you can just set the `foreach` statement to a variable like `data = foreach ($User in $UserList) {`.